# ComboBox Binding an enum property is not working C# Winforms

Tags: c#, binding, combobox, enums

Hi I have a function inside a user control that will display and create user control and bind it values depend on the type of the property

I was able to do the text property but binding a combobox with enum is not working for me here is the following code

```
public void DisplayProperties(object obj)
    {
        // get Display Name
        DisplayNameAttribute groupNameAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(obj.GetType(), typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
        if (groupNameAttribute != null)
        {
            propertyPanel.Controls.Add(DisplayCategory(groupNameAttribute.DisplayName));
        }
        else
        {
            propertyPanel.Controls.Add(DisplayCategory(obj.GetType().Name));
        }

        PropertyInfo[] propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in propInfo)
        {
            BrowsableAttribute attrib = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(BrowsableAttribute)) as BrowsableAttribute;
            if(attrib == null || attrib.Browsable == true)
            {
                DisplayNameAttribute propName = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property.GetType(), typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
                string displayName;
                if (propName != null)
                {
                    displayName = propName.DisplayName;
                }
                else
                {
                    displayName = property.Name;
                }
                object attrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
                DescriptionAttribute propertyDescription = attrs as DescriptionAttribute;
                if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                {
                    ComboBoxProperty comboProperty = new ComboBoxProperty();
                    comboProperty.ComboDisplayName = displayName;
                    comboProperty.propertyComboBox.DataSource = property;
                    comboProperty.propertyComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", obj, displayName);
                    comboProperty.Description = "test";// propertyDescription.Description;
                    propertyPanel.Controls.Add(comboProperty);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBoxProperty textBoxProperty = new TextBoxProperty();
                    //if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    //{
                    textBoxProperty.TextDisplayName = displayName;
                    textBoxProperty.valueTb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", obj, displayName)); //property.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();
                    textBoxProperty.Description = "test";//propertyDescription.Description;
                    textBoxProperty.Top = _PropertyPosition;
                    _PropertyPosition += textBoxProperty.Height;
                    propertyPanel.Controls.Add(textBoxProperty);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this function is called from a form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       TestObject textObject = new TestObject();
        textObject.TestString = "testing";
        textObject.TestEnum = TestObject.MyEnum.A;
        propertyGrid1.DisplayProperties(textObject);

    }


}
public class TestObject
{
    public enum MyEnum 
    {
        A,
        B
    }
    public string TestString { get; set; }
    //public int TestInteger { get; set; }
    //public double TestDouble { get; set; }
    public MyEnum TestEnum {get; set;}

}
```

I want the combobox to contain all the enum value and the selected value to show.
let me know if how I can fix my issue

**EDIT**

I did some reading and I was able to get the enum to work but the databinding is not working I m sure this because of the ValueMember if not from the DataBidning itself  here is my updated code 
this code from the UserControl class that contains 2 usercontrol classes one for ComboBox and the second for textbox

```
public partial class PropertyGrid : TouchObjectListBox
{
     int _PropertyPosition = 0;
    public PropertyGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void DisplayProperties(object obj)
    {
        // get Display Name
        DisplayNameAttribute groupNameAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(obj.GetType(), typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
        if (groupNameAttribute != null)
        {
            propertyPanel.Controls.Add(DisplayCategory(groupNameAttribute.DisplayName));
        }
        else
        {
            propertyPanel.Controls.Add(DisplayCategory(obj.GetType().Name));
        }

        PropertyInfo[] propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in propInfo)
        {
            BrowsableAttribute attrib = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(BrowsableAttribute)) as BrowsableAttribute;
            if(attrib == null || attrib.Browsable == true)
            {
                DisplayNameAttribute propName = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property.GetType(), typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;
                string displayName;
                if (propName != null)
                {
                    displayName = propName.DisplayName;
                }
                else
                {
                    displayName = property.Name;
                }
                object attrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
                DescriptionAttribute propertyDescription = attrs as DescriptionAttribute;
                if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                {
                    ComboBoxProperty comboProperty = new ComboBoxProperty();
                    comboProperty.ComboDisplayName = displayName;
                    comboProperty.propertyComboBox.ValueMember = displayName;
                    comboProperty.propertyComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(property.PropertyType);
                    comboProperty.propertyComboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue",obj, displayName));
                    comboProperty.Description = "test";
                    comboProperty.Top = _PropertyPosition;
                    _PropertyPosition += comboProperty.Height;
                    propertyPanel.Controls.Add(comboProperty);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBoxProperty textBoxProperty = new TextBoxProperty();
                    //if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    //{
                    textBoxProperty.TextDisplayName = displayName;
                    textBoxProperty.valueTb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", obj, displayName));
                    textBoxProperty.Description = "test";// propertyDescription.Description;
                    textBoxProperty.Top = _PropertyPosition;
                    _PropertyPosition += textBoxProperty.Height;
                    propertyPanel.Controls.Add(textBoxProperty);
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Label DisplayCategory(string groupName)
    {
        Label groupLabel = new Label();
        groupLabel.ForeColor = SystemPens.ControlLightLight.Color;
        groupLabel.BackColor = SystemPens.ControlDark.Color;
        groupLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        groupLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        groupLabel.Text = groupName;
        groupLabel.Width = propertyPanel.Width;
        groupLabel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
        groupLabel.Top = _PropertyPosition;
        _PropertyPosition += groupLabel.Height;
        return groupLabel;
    }
}
```

This Form that call the UserControl

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      List<TestObject> testObject = new List<TestObject>();

      testObject.Add(new TestObject() { TestString = "testing1", TestEnum = TestObject.MyEnum.A });
      testObject.Add(new TestObject() { TestString = "testing2", TestEnum = TestObject.MyEnum.B });
        foreach(var obj in testObject)
        {
            propertyGrid1.DisplayProperties(obj);
        }

    }


}
public class TestObject
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    //[CategoryOrder("Beam Parameters", 2)]
    [DisplayName("Test String")]
    [Description("testString description")]
    public string TestString { get; set; }
    //public int TestInteger { get; set; }
    //public double TestDouble { get; set; }
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        A,
        B
    }
    private MyEnum m_cycleMode = MyEnum.A;
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DisplayName("Cycle Mode")]
    [Description("Specifies how this process step is processed")]
    public MyEnum TestEnum { get { return m_cycleMode; } set { m_cycleMode = value; } }


}
```

the issue is when I load the application combobox is not selecting the initial value and when I change it, it will call the property MyEnum and get the result but not displaying the selected value the value go to blank again

any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, what you want to do, but, when I understand well, you want to use the value of an enum to bind to a e.g. a text of another control?

In your code you set the DataSource of the binding to the reflected property. This is completely unnecessary, as you can specify the name of the property you want to bind to.

The second you need to do, is to add the values of the enum to the ComboBox you create. Otherwise you wouldn't have any items in it.
The following shows an example how you can do this:

```
foreach (ETestEnum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ETestEnum)))
{
    this.combo.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = value });
}
```

The `ComboBoxItem` is just an example and maybe not what you want. Instead you could also use an own class with two properties let's say `Description` and `Value` or similar. You can configure them then with `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` on the `ComboBox`.

Comment: How I can add the value of the enum in ComboBox this where I'm having the issue, I want to add all the values of enum in a combobox

Answer (score 0):

You need the assign the property's value to the itemSource & not the property itself:

```
comboProperty.propertyComboBox.DataSource = property;
```

Add the following function to the usercontrol:

```
private void SetBindingForComboBoxWithEnumItems(ComboBox cmb,Type enumType)
{
  List<KeyValuePair<object, string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<object,string>>();
  List<Tuple<object, string, int>> enumList=Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<object>().Select(x=>Tuple.Create(x, x.ToString(), (int)x)).ToList();
  foreach (var idx in enumList)
  {
     values.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, string>(idx.Item1, idx.Item2));
  }
  cmb.ItemsSource = values;
  cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
  cmb.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
}
```

change the above code to:

```
if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
{
   ComboBox cmb=new ComboBox();
   Binding myBinding = new Binding();
   myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(property.Name);
   myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
   myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(cmb, ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, myBinding);
   SetBindingForComboBoxWithEnumItems(cmb,obj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetType());
   propertyPanel.Controls.Add(cmb);
}
```

Comment: It is not working, not sure if my enum property is wrong, cause I want to add all the enum information into the datasource not the specific value which is A in my case here, but I want A to be shown as selected item in the combobox. Any Idea

Comment: check the update. basically you cannot bind the enum directly to comboBox.But what are you trying to achieve??

Comment: Hi Nikita, could you please check my edit update, I was able to make it work but the databinding is not quite working

Comment: my idea is to create same concept of a property grid where i can have a control over it, every type of property will have it is own usercontrol all this usercontrol will be combined in one usercontrol, and this need databinding data in the case of combobox that will represent the data of enum and update the selected enum data from the user